# how do you clone a project from github into the same project

Tags: android, git, android-studio

In android studio how do you git clone a project from github into the same project?

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to do. What project is “the same project”?

Comment: I mean i want to git clone a project into my main project like the one i am working on.But when i try to cone it pop up a new window.

Comment: You really need to be more precise about what you want to do, what *exact* problem you are encountering, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to check out some library and add it as a dependency to your (gradle based?) project. 
The prefered way would be to checkout it separately and built it as a library project. And if you have maven you can then install it to your local repository.

The other way (and probably what are you trying to achieve) is to add it as a submodule of your local repository.

`git submodule add git://repourl.git yourSubmoduleFolder`

Then you can add this library as a module dependency to your application module. (You don't have to use git submodules, you can always just get the repo as a zip and extract it into your project)

If you put your library under libraries folder in your project then you can do it like this.

1. Add this to your settings.gradle

   `include ':libraries:yourLibraryModuleName'`
2. Add this to your build.gradle

   ```
   dependencies { 
       compile project(':libraries:yourLibraryModuleName')
   }
   ```
3. You should now be able to build your application with the submodule

Please note that this was just a quick answer, you can find more info on both gradle submodules and gradle module dependencies here on StackOverflow. I guess this should be enough to point you in a right direction.

Comment: How do i put a zip file in my project?

Comment: You have to extract it at first..you can either drag&drop it to its destination location in android studio, or do the same thing with your file manager

Comment: I forgot to tell you i use a mac.

Comment: I forgot to ask does it matter where i put the file from github?

Answer (score 0):

It does not. However it's a good practice to put it in libraries or libs,...folder